# Pulling desired data from Salesforce Opportunity using Apex

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

How do I push sellected data from Salesforce Opportunity (client name, cliente id, Products, product ids, price per item, discount etc to google sheet when opportunity staged is updated to won close

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @aoristdual. I have no salesforce background. I tried it with Zapier, it only pulls 1 product details from the opportunity which has multiple products. Then I tried creating a flow in Salesforce , but after setting-up the trigger, I do not what and how to do it.

Comment: You dont give any specifics about what you want to do. Is this an existing Sheet? Do you want it to create a new sheet for each opportunity? How are you displaying the list of products?